# Jump to/load a storyboard from a xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have a view controller created from a xib file and I wanna make it the entry point of my app when it is launched for the first time. All the other view controllers are created in a storyboard file, which will be used as the main interface for subsequent launches. Is there any way to jump to the storyboard from the xib? Also how do I use different view controllers as entry point for first-time and non-first-time launches?

Answer (score 0):

you can load xib in storyboard by 
UIView *childView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];

and switch between view controllers as entry point in applicatin didFinishLaunchimgWithOptions